# How can I disable a bind on a div

Tags: jquery, bind

Supposing I have this HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="topbar">
        First block here.
        <p>Another block here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

How can I disable the `bind` on the `div#topbar` ?

```
$('body').bind('mouseover mouseout', function(event) { });
```

I already try this without success:

```
if($(event.target).is('#topbar')) { //do nothing }
else { //do stuff }
```

Actually, my problem is if I make a mouseover on the `p` tag, the code don't work.

**PS:** I do not have any control on the HTML so I must use common tag like `body`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating another div for the rest of the body:

```
<body>
    <div id="topbar">hello
        <div>How<br>are<br>you<br>today<br>?</div>
    </div>
    <div id="mouseEvent">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="container"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and js:

```
$('body').bind('mouseover mouseout', function(event) { 
    var list = $('#topbar').find( "*" );
    if($(event.target).is("#topbar") || $(event.target).is(list)) { 
        alert("hello");
    } else { 
        alert("footer");
    }
});
```

Updated: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sz624px1/2/)

Comment: As I do not know if #mouseEvent exists on the website I can't use it. I must use common tag like body.

Comment: @PacPac ok one moment

Comment: @PacPac Updated answer

Comment: It's already what I have tried without success (see my question). If there is some others div into `#topbar`? Do this code works? Or I need to enumerate all the `div` into my condition?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sz624px1/1/ Because the `How are you today?` is inside the `div#topbar` it must alert me `hello` not `footer`. This is actually my problem.

Comment: @PacPac ok one moment

Comment: It works. Could you please explain a little bit what you do here `$('#topbar').find( "*" )` ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PacPac it gets all the elements inside `topbar`